# Matching date format in Teradata YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: validation, date, pattern-matching, teradata

I am fairly new to Teradata. I have a transaction date column in the source which has some valid and invalid values. What I need to do is fetch the valid values which are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS` and pass a null to target for all the invalid values

The transformation rule is : If format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS` then move source to target else move null to target.

Comment: post some valid and invalid rows. It will help in giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `left join` your column with the `Sys_Calendar tables`, and using `COALESCE` in the SEL part should get it to work.

If you still have issues, cast your date into a format that matches `sys calendar`.
Invalid dates will be returned as `NULL`.

Comment: So the query worked but i have a slight problem my date column is defined as char in source so when i run the query after joining its returning junks values and not valid dates

Comment: Hi Juvelle, please convert the char to date using cast(column as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') and then do the join. Ideally if you have huge data, its best to take help of a temporary table and pre-cast the datatype to date. Then perform the join on the temporary table and sys calendar. Please post your query so far, if you need us to look into it.

Comment: sel a.datecol

FROM mydatabase.mytable A

LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR CAL

ON (CALENDAR_DATE(FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')(char(20)))=A.datecol

Comment: sel cast(datecol as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM mydatabase.mytable A LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR CAL ON (CALENDAR_DATE(FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')(char(20)))=A.datecol i casted it it is throwing an error which says 'invalid date'

Comment: can you try the following query?  sel cast(datecol as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM mydatabase.mytable A LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR CAL ON (CALENDAR_DATE(FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')(char(20)))=cast(A.datecol as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Comment: It says invalid date supplied to mytable.datecol

Comment: Hmm...so the cast is failing due to bad records in the mytable.datecol. We will have to filter those records out.  Can you post some sample records ? One idea would be to use select datecol, char_length(datecol) as len1 from mytable group by len1. See the rows with differing lengths and post here please. We can then use the length to filter invalid rows.

Comment: 2016-03-12                          
2016-03-01                          
2016-03-12                          
2016-03-01                          
2016-03-12  these are few values which satisfy two other conditions(i.e if transcode='detail' and transname='model' )in the table .SO the entire column has other values too which do not satisfy the condition .A few other values are 1.0                                 
1.034                               
?
1.0                                 
0                                   
0.0836

Comment: I think you meant the entire row has other values too which do not satisfy the condition. Lets use the following strategy : create temporary table mytable1 as select * from mydatabase.mytable where char_length(datecol) = 10 and substr(datecol,5,1) = "-" and substr(datecol,8,1) = "-" and transcode='detail' and transname='model'; Now use the temporary table as your reference.  Use coalesce to convert any unmatched records in source to desired value. Select coalesce(stg.datecol,'NULL') as datecol, stg.* from mytable as src left outer join mytable1 as tmp1 on src.datecol = tmp1.datecol;

Comment: No those are column values .I finally got the query working it returns only the date values that match from the my datecolumn but now the issue is  source has 149 entries and target 80 .I guess thats because not all data is loaded into target .Thanks Tammy for your help

Comment: The *invalid date* error  is caused by the time portion, you need to either `CAST(datecol AS TIMESTAMP)` or `CAST(SUBSTRING(datecol FROM 1 FOR 10) AS DATE)`